# How to manipulate ManyToMany relations with additional attributes in twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm new to symfony2, 6 weeks experience and I have a problem.
I have to use a ManyToMany relation with additional attributes between a user and an event, so they have become 2 relations ( two OneToMany relations with the intermediate entity ) and that part of coding is correct.
I have an event page that displays the event details ( title, date, etc.) button. This is where my problem is:

I want to check if the current user is already subscribed to the event and display two different buttons depending on that : Subscribe/Unsubscribe

So far, the best that I could think of is this twig code:

```
{% for user_event in event.user_event%}
        {% if  app.user.id == user_event.user.id %}
            Already subscribed! <button> Unsubscribe </button>
            {% else %}
                You are not subscribed! What are you waiting for!?
                <button> Subscribe </button>
            {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The code above iterates through the rows of the intermediate table where
particular event and then test all the users subscribed to that event, the problem with this is that the else condition would be true except for the current user, this approach will output something like:

You are not subscribed! What you are waiting for!?
Already subscribed!
You are not subscribed! What you are waiting for!?
You are not subscribed! What you are waiting for!?
You are not subscribed! What you are waiting for!?
You are not subscribed! What you are waiting for!? .

Isn't there a way do something like this : (this might not be coding correct but it clarifies what I want to do)

```
{% if  event.user_event.user(app.user.id) %}
        Already subscribed! <button> Unsubscribe </button>
        {% else %}
            You are not subscribed! What are you waiting for!?
             <button> subscribe </button>
        {% endif %}
```

I tried with:

```
{%if app.user.id == event.user_event.user.id %}
```

but it doesn't work and gives me this error:

Method "user" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in OCUserBundle:Event:view_event.html.twig at line 35.

Am I missing something? help would be appreciated and if you want to check my entities tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do your check and then output based on the results:

```
{% set subscribed = false %}
{% for user_event in event.user_event%}
    {% if  app.user.id == user_event.user.id %}
        {% set subscribed = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if subscribed %}
    Already subscribed! <button> Unsubscribe </button>
{% else %}
    You are not subscribed! What are you waiting for!?
    <button> Subscribe </button>
{% endif %}
```

I think a better approach would be to generate a query to get the list of events the user is subscribed to.  Grabbing every user for every event seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: I think a better approach is to implement a isSubscribed($id_event) function inside the user entity and make the test : if app.user.isSubscribed(event.id) in twig, this will output true or false with no mess. But after doing a lot of research I think coupling the entity to the entity manager is a bad practise, so I'm going to create a twig extension that does the job, something like:

Is subscribed($id_event,$id_event). Just want to know before investing time on it: is this feasible? Is it's a bad practice? . Thank you.

Comment: Your is_subscribed will stay need a query for each event.  I'd suggest looking at how you can get all the events a user is subscribed to with one query.  You will learn a bit about queries and will end up with a faster system.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I ended up with a twig extension function that return true or false like this:

```
<?php
namespace OC\UserBundle\Services\Twig\Extension;

class AzouzExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
 protected $em;

 public function __construct($em)
 {
    $this->em = $em;
 }

 public function getFunctions()
 {
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('test_inscription', array($this, 'aa'))
    );
 }

 public function getName()
 {
    return 'test_inscription';
 }   

 public function aa($uid,$eid)
 {
    $qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('ue')
       ->from('OCUserBundle:InscritEvent', 'ue')
       ->where('ue.apprenant = :x and ue.evenement = :y' )
       ->setParameter('x', $uid)
       ->setParameter('y', $eid)
            ;
    $query=$qb->getQuery();

    if($query->getResult())
    {return true;}
    else {return false;}
  }
 }
```

and in twig page :

```
{% if test_inscription(app.user.id,evenement.id)%}
you are already subscribed :)
{% else %}
</button><a href="#">Subscribe</a> </button>
{% endif %}
```

May not be the best approach but it works.